# How to sandbox an assembly or C# source file

Tags: c#

We want to provide some programmability features to our clients,
so we allow them to write their own code,
but they must not have access to system features, like

```
File.Delete( "test.txt" );
```

We partially accomplished this by not allowing global or local **using** statements.

But the users still would be able to access all .NET features by writing fully qualified names, like:

```
System.IO.File.Delete( "test.txt" );
```

Do you know of ways to restrict certain source files, or complete assemblies, from accessing system functions?

Comment: What comes to mind is to make docker pod. Restrict it as much as possible, leaving only port for 8080, execute your assemblies there.

Comment: Create/use a scripting language that only has the features that you want them to have and not opening them to the complete framework? Or run that code in a user context that misses all access rights you think they shouldn't have.

Comment: Using Docker features is an excellent idea. The final product will be run in Docker anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .net framework (not net core or net5+) you could run the user's code in a separate AppDomain with restricted permissions.

Just a few hints (there are a lot of other permissions you can set):

```
var setup = new AppDomainSetup();

var perm = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);

perm.AddPermission(
       new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

perm.AddPermission(
       new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, "PathToReadOnlyFolder"));

var userCodeDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("UserCodeDomain", null, setup, perm);
```

Comment: It's only running in .NET core (.NET 6 and 7 upward)

Answer (score 1):

The most secure alternative would likely be to create a new user that *only* has permission to run the specific program, and some way to communicate with your main process. Users are the main security primitive most operating systems, so that is probably what you need to use.

Trying to restrict the source code sounds like it will be next to impossible, since it was never intended as a security barrier.

That said, I would probably either use some smaller scripting language that is designed to run in a sandbox, something like javascript or Lua. Or to run your system in a virtual machine, or docker container, specific for each customer, so that they could only possibly access their own data, or break their own system. Just remember to keep frequent backups so you can restore the system when they break it.

Comment: Very good points. The restricted-user approach probably is the most secure option.